# AAD Jwt token validates on localhost but not on server

Tags: jwt, token, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm working on a .net core 2.0 web api and have tried to secure it with a Azure Active Directory token. My client application generates a token and sends it to the api to be authorized. All works fine when I run my api in localhost, however when I deploy it to our test server suddenly I get a 401 Unauthorized error. I've checked that the configuration files are correct on the deployed version. Could there be something with server settings that blocks or changes the workings of AAD? I've been told it shouldn't matter where it's running. Is that true or can server configurations interfere with reaching the AAD for validation somehow?

Comment: Could you show how you have configured the JWT Bearer handler? Usually it validates that the token issuer matches the AAD tenant expected (or does not check in case of multi-tenant) and that the audienc (aud) in the token matches the valid audience set. You can check these by using a tool such as https://jwt.ms.

Comment: We installed SSL certs on the server and then it started working. I didn't know that was a requirement for using AAD tokens. Does anyone know more about that?

Answer (score 1):

If your AAD token validates on localhost it most likely will not validate on the published app, and vice versa. In your app registration, ensure that the reply URL is set to your published homepage URL (i.e. https://myapp.azurewebsites.net).

Check also to ensure that your web.config matches your app registration.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the URL where you deployed your application as a Reply URL for your application in the Azure portal? See [What to change when you deploy the sample to Azure](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore#what-to-change-when-you-deploy-the-sample-to-azure)